# MFC C++ How to make Edit Control's background transparent?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, controls, edit

I want to make edit control's background transparent and change text's color to white. I can do both of them with this function, the only problem is that when you type on edit control, text keeps overlapping, follow the link for an example. I believe the problem is `NULL_BRUSH`, which makes background transparent, because if I change only the text color it works fine, unfortunately I need both.
How can I do this?

```
HBRUSH  CDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDc, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor){

HBRUSH hbr = NULL;  

switch (nCtlColor) {
case CTLCOLOR_EDIT:
    if (pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == editControl){
        pDc->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
        pDc->SetBkColor(TRANSPARENT);
        pDc->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 255, 255));
        hbr = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    }

    break;
default:
    hbr = CDialogEx::OnCtlColor(pDc, pWnd, nCtlColor);
}

return hbr;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `SetBkColor(TRANSPARENT)` is invalid. The argument for `SetBkColor` should be a `COLORREF` value. You need `SetBkColor(my_color)`. Also create a permanent brush, example `static HBRUSH hbr = CreateSolidBrush(my_color)` then return that brush for the edit control. Creating a transparent edit control is a harder, it doesn't look like you need it.

Comment: What does make transparent edit's control background is the combination of SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT) && return NULL_BRUSH, so for sure this works and it's not the problem. The problem is the text, it seems like it keeps being painted over and over.

Comment: From [WM_CTLCOLOREDIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcoloredit): *"If an application processes this message, it must return the handle of a brush. **The system uses the brush to paint the background of the edit control.**"* A `NULL_BRUSH` results in painting that does nothing. You shouldn't be surprised, that your control's background doesn't get erased, and all output is rendered on top of what's already there.

Comment: Well that's the only way I found to get to work the transparent background effect, otherwise I could only change its color